# Getting a client token from Identity Duende Server in Angular

Tags: angular, jwt, token, angular14, duende-identity-server

For a project I am running a .NET API server, Duende Identity Server, and the client side is an Angular app.

When there is a user logged in, the client app can do all the CRUD operations, when there is no user logged in it can only do the read operations.

I first did this by putting the [Authorize] decorator on the endpoints only a logged in user can access.

But this means that anybody that knows the urls to the endpoints can access that information. This is not considered good practice, so if there is no user logged in, I want to send a client token with my request, so in my API server I can respond correctly on my endpoints.

I am able to do this in Postman, by configuring my new token as follows:

[PostMan Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev15W.png)

And then using the token it gets to do the read operation on the API.

But I am unable to reproduce this in Angular. This is my code so far:

`

```
getToken() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Authorization', `Basic client:secret`);
    headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    const requestOptions = { headers: headers };
    let body = {
      "grant_type": "client_credentials",
      "client_id": "client",
      "client_secret": "secret",
      "scopes": "api",
      "response_type": "id_token token"
    }
    this.http.post("https://localhost:5001/connect/token", body, requestOptions).subscribe( result => {
       console.log(result);
     })
  }
```

`
I have tried endless variations, but I keep getting a status code 400 error:"invalid_request"

Cors has been configured in my API-server Program.cs file as follows:

```
            builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
                optionsBuilder =>
                {
                    optionsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });
```

This is what the IdentityServer logs when I request the token:

```
[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration from origin: http://localhost:4200

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
CORS request made for path: /connect/token from origin: http://localhost:4200

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Services.InMemoryCorsPolicyService
Client list checked and origin: http://localhost:4200 is allowed

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Services.InMemoryCorsPolicyService
Client list checked and origin: http://localhost:4200 is allowed

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:4200

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:4200

[08:50:01 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.

[08:50:01 Information] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware
HTTP OPTIONS /connect/token responded 204 in 14.3206 ms

[08:50:01 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
CORS request made for path: /connect/token from origin: http://localhost:4200

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Services.InMemoryCorsPolicyService
Client list checked and origin: http://localhost:4200 is allowed

[08:50:01 Information] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:4200

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
Start discovery request

[08:50:01 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.

[08:50:01 Information] Duende.IdentityServer.Services.KeyManagement.KeyManager
Active signing key found with kid D576C7CF6598DABD3F65CBC5B29D6FD4 for alg RS256. Expires in 83.00:58:45. Retires in 97.00:58:45

[08:50:01 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.

[08:50:01 Information] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware
HTTP GET /.well-known/openid-configuration responded 200 in 35.6220 ms

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /connect/token matched to endpoint type Token

[08:50:01 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Token, successfully created handler: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint

[08:50:01 Information] Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token

[08:50:01 Warning] Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint

[08:50:01 Information] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware
HTTP POST /connect/token responded 400 in 39.8834 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make requests from JavaScript, you also need to configure CORS correctly. Postman does not need CORS, but browsers do.

I would look at the failing request and response using a tool like https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Also, perhaps post a sample response in your request?

I would also see the logs in IdentityServer for clues why the request fails.

Comment: CORS is already configured, I added the details to my question, as well as the IdentityServer logs.

Comment: I think you should look in Fiddler for what the problem is. Do you add UseCors before or after UseIdentityServer()? I would place  app.UseCors(); before            app.UseIdentityServer();

Comment: If you get 400 status code, then that is not an authentication or authorization problem, it might be a CORS problem. I would look at the debug log for ASP.NET Core as well.

Comment: What does the request/reponse with status code 400 look like?